# Display image stored in BLOB database in symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, blob

I load my image (blob data ) in my GETer Entity
When I just return ($this->foto) in my GETer I see :Resource id #284 on the screen
When I change my GETer like this : return stream_get_contents($this->foto);
I see these : ���JFIF���   ( ,,,,,,,, ( and more )

In my Controller a call the index.html.twig to show all my entities

```
    /**
 * Lists all Producten entities.
 *
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('CustomCMSBundle:Producten')->findAll();

    return $this->render('CustomCMSBundle:Producten:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
}
```

Now in my views ( index.html.twig ) I like to show the picture

```
       {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img  src="{{ entity.foto}}" alt="" width="80" height="80" />
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ entity.foto }}
            </td>
            <td>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('cms_producten_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">show</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('cms_producten_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">edit</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

But I don't see the picture ?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `<img src="(raw image)">` instead of `<img src="(image's url)">`

A quick solution is to encode your image in base64 and embed it.

<kbd>Controller</kbd>

```
$images = array();
foreach ($entities as $key => $entity) {
  $images[$key] = base64_encode(stream_get_contents($entity->getFoto()));
}

// ...

return $this->render('CustomCMSBundle:Producten:index.html.twig', array(
    'entities' => $entities,
    'images' => $images,
));
```

<kbd>View</kbd>

```
{% for key, entity in entities %}
  {# ... #}
  <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ images[key] }}" />
  {# ... #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hallo Alain, No error but the picture is empty, I changed it to jpeg       src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ entity.fotoB64 }}" because the blob data is JPEG

Comment: Please check my edit-- i guess the property accessor can't access hot properties.

Answer (score 0):

in your entity write your image getter like this:

```
public function getFoto()
{
    return imagecreatefromstring($this->foto);
}
```

and use it instead of the object "foto" property.

php doc for the function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Comment: Hallo Udan, when using your info I get the error , An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template "Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format in the Twig file

Answer (score 0):

A more direct way, without extra work in the controller:

**In the Entity Class**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="blob", nullable=true)
 */
private $photo;

private $rawPhoto;

public function displayPhoto()
{
    if(null === $this->rawPhoto) {
        $this->rawPhoto = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode(stream_get_contents($this->getPhoto()));
    }

    return $this->rawPhoto;
}
```

**In the view**

```
<img src="{{ entity.displayPhoto }}">
```

### EDIT

Thanks to @b.enoit.be answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270314/image-blob-showing-only-once-in-browser/55271122#55271122), I could improve this code so the image can be displayed more than once.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said before you must use base64 method, but for a better performance and usability, the correct option is creating a custom twig filter (Twig extension) as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/templating/twig_extension.html) .

```
<?php


namespace Your\Namespace;


use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class TwigExtensions extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('base64', [$this, 'twig_base64_filter']),
        ];
    }

    function twig_base64_filter($source)
    {   if($source!=null) {           
           return base64_encode(stream_get_contents($source));
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

In your template:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ entity.photo | base64 }}">
```