# Dispaly Blob image from database using Symfony Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, blob

I am trying to display images for each blog post. I have them set up so that it is displaying the blog name, excerpt and published date, but I am struggling to get the images which I have stored as Blobs. I have attached my code, which is in 3 parts: the entity, which has set and get variables; the `index.html.twig` file, which is the front end (how I am displaying the image); and the `post.orm.yml` file, which is to set the type of item the image is, i.e., BLOB.

### Post entity

```
/**
 * Set image
 *
 * @param /post/blob $image
 *
 * @return Post
 */
public function setimage($image)
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get image
 *
 * @return post/blob
 */
public function getimage()
{
    return $this->image;
}
```

### index.html.twig

```
{{post.image}}
```

### post.orm.yml

```
Shannon\BlogBundle\Entity\Post:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: Shannon\BlogBundle\Repository\PostRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        title:
            type: string
            length: '255'
        body:
            type: text
        publishedAt:
            type: datetime
            column: published_at
        image:
            type:image
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

### postcontroller.php

public function imageAction($id)
{
    $image =  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ShannonBlogBundle:Image')->findOneBy(array('id'=> $id));
    return $this->render('index.html.twig', array('image' => $image));
}
}
    public function imageAction($id)
{
    $image =  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ShannonBlogBundle:Image')->findOneBy(array('id'=> $id));
    return $this->render('index.html.twig', array('image' => $image)``);
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display image stored in BLOB database in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294077/display-image-stored-in-blob-database-in-symfony)

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your image in **base64** and simply embed it in the HTML:

```
<img  src="data:image/png;base64,{{ imageBase64 }}" />
```

Comment: hi i have tried <img  src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ post.image }}" /> in index.html.twig and it shows resourse #419

Comment: Try in controller 
$imageBase64  = base64_encode(stream_get_contents($post.getImage());

and pass it to twig

Comment: i keep receiving a parse error when i tried that i have no idea whats going it is able to retrive the rest of the blog information

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$imageBase64' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ';' or '{'

Comment: That's not parse error, it is syntax error as it said.

Comment: public function imageAction($id) { 
        $image = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ShannonBlogBundle:Image')->findOneBy(array('id'=> $id));
        return $this->render('index.html.twig', array('image' => $image)); 
    }

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''id'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'